# "From" field in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo

I'm having a problem with the "from/reply-to" field when a message was sent to an email add.. it does not show the current user email address where it came from..

This is the code of openerp 7 in declaring a default from field..

```
def _get_default_from(self, cr,uid, context=None):
    this = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid,uid, context=context)
    if this.alias_domain:
    return '%s@%s' % (this.alias_name, this.alias_domain)
    elif this.email:
    return this.email
    raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Action!'), _("Unable to send email, please configure the sender's email address or alias."))
```

Answer (score 0):

In E-mail **from address** come from **ir.mail_server (Outgoing Mail Server)**, in which **Username** will be the from address for outgoing mails

Comment: hi Arya, thanks so much , but how about the 'reply-to' field? It does not show when I view it and also if I want to reply, the from address shows not the user email address?